# Make flutter widgets overlap

Tags: flutter, widget, stack

card2(),
card3(
text: 'Transfer',
bgColor: Colors.white,
textColor: Colors.black
),
],
I wanted the cards to overlap each other, so I used a widget called Stack, but I can't control it. If it's a duplicate, I'll ask because I don't know which widget you're using.

I also tried using positioned, which is an attribute of the widget called stack, and tried using various attributes, but only an error came up.

Comment: can you post the code snippet and the error log to get more clear way to approach ??

Comment: 예외가 발생했습니다.
FlutterError (BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
These invalid constraints were provided to RenderDecoratedBox's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
  RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:279:14)
The offending constraints were:
  BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, h=200.0))

Comment: code?  you can edit your questions to update

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).